# What's the difference between a blueprint and a template in Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask, web-development-server

I'm self-learning web development, and I was confused about how blueprint and templates were different.

Blueprints support "common patterns within an application or across applications" - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/ but I don't see why templates can't suffice

Also, are these standard web terminology or just Flask specific?

Comment: A template is a text (file) with a markup language that will be rendered into a resulting output. While a blueprint is a whole (sub) web application that is bundled to be integrated into a flask application at a given sub path.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, could you clarify what you mean by it being the web app? I don't really understand how they work

Comment: If you are working with a web application framework like Flask and you don't know what a web application is, what are words you know so I could use them in a description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blueprint**:

A Blueprint object works similarly to a Flask application object, but it is not actually an application. Rather it is a blueprint of how to construct or extend an application. It is particularly used for scaling large projects.

Blueprints are sets of applications in a application.

*Blueprints may render templates to display the requested data.*

**Template**:

Templates are used for rendering HTML document which are used to display in users browser. Templates file can be either static content or placeholder for dynamic data.

*Templates are rendered by blueprint or an app which they pass data to templates.*